# Android getResources/getIdentifier not returning ID

Tags: android

I have code like tthis:

```
String s = "replace__menu__" + data.imageid + ".png";
int RID = this.getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(s, "drawable-hdpi", getPackageName());
```

The *String s =* instruction sets a value that is the same as one of names in my res/drawable-hdpi folder. However, the returned value sets *RID* to the value *0*

Any idea why my code is not working? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: remove the extentions from s, String s = "replace__menu__" + data.imageid;

Comment: Thanks. I still get the same problem though.

Comment: do you have inside you res/drawable folder a png named "replace__menu__+"data.imageid?

Comment: Well... Viewing it again, it would appear the code *now* works for most images except one. (A transparent image.) I *did* make a naming mistake for this one. (And unluckily the one I used for checking the advices given here.) Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
String s = "replace__menu__" + data.imageid;  // image name is needed without extention
int RID = this.getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(s, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Comment: your comment-- image name is needed without extention....worked for me.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

```
".png" is not part of a ressource name
"drawable-hdpi" I would try just 'drawable' instead
```

Comment: Thanks. I still get the same problem though.